# Возврат массива из функции

Tags: php

Подскажите, как возвратить список удалённых файлов в виде массива без использования глобальной переменной?

```
function fileDelete ($folder)
{
    $all_in_folder = scandir($folder);
    foreach ($all_in_folder as $object) {
        if ($object == '.' || $object == '..') continue;
        $path_to_object = "$folder" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "$object";
        if (is_dir($path_to_object)) {
            fileDelete($path_to_object);
        } else {
            unlink($path_to_object);
            echo "Удалённый файл: $path_to_object <br />";
        }
    }
}

fileDelete('C:\test');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fileDelete ($folder)
{
    static $delFilesArr = []; // <---------
    $all_in_folder = scandir($folder);
    foreach ($all_in_folder as $object) {
        if ($object == '.' || $object == '..') continue;
        $path_to_object = "$folder" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "$object";
        if (is_dir($path_to_object)) {
            fileDelete($path_to_object);
        } else {
            unlink($path_to_object);
            echo "Удалённый файл: $path_to_object <br />";
            $delFilesArr[] = $path_to_object; // <------
        }
    }
    return $delFilesArr;
}

print_r(fileDelete('C:\test'));
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ. А можно без использования глобальной переменной?

Comment: можно возвращать массив, добавил в ответ (глобальной переменной в примере нет).

Comment: у меня почему-то возвращается пустой массив: https://i.imgur.com/5FptSpy.png

Comment: объявите $delFilesArr как static, дописал в ответ. Не учёл рекурсию